# Page Speed. Подгрузка шрифтов

Tags: css, шрифты

По рекомендации гугла я использовал подгрузку шрифтов таким образом

```
<link rel="preload" href="<?= get_template_directory_uri()?>/assets/fonts/Pravda_Fixed_Pitch.otf" as="font" crossorigin>
```

Всё отлично, вот только шрифт этот использовать я не могу. То есть `font-family: 'Pravda_Fixed_Pitch';` Не работает. Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Файл шрифта имеет у вас название "Pravda_Fixed_Pitch.otf", вангую, что семейство надо указывать без подчёркиваний с пробелами, а может и слитно. Как-нибудь так: `font-family: "Pravda Fixed Pitch";` или `font-family: "PravdaFixedPitch";`

Answer (score 0):

Не припомню, чтобы я подгружал шрифты в формате otf, однако часто были ttf, eot, svg, woof и даже woof2.  И происходит это не от жиру, а потому что разные браузеры на разных платформах требуют разных форматов шрифтов. А кроме того, в css3 имеется отличный инструмент для подгрузки шрифтов, [font-face](https://html5book.ru/pravilo-font-face/) называется. Использовать его в css можно как-ниббудь так:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "OpenSans";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/OpenSansRegular/OpenSansRegular.eot");
    src: url("../fonts/OpenSansRegular/OpenSansRegular.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), 
         url("../fonts/OpenSansRegular/OpenSansRegular.woff") format("woff"),
         url("../fonts/OpenSansRegular/OpenSansRegular.ttf") format("truetype");
```

Тут вам и разные типы шрифтов, но с одним и тем же начертанием подключить можно. И использовать затем можно именно указанное в свойстве `font-family`название.

Comment: Да. я знаю про font-face, но вопрос в гугле. Ему не нравится такая подгрузка, даже с font-display: swap;

Comment: К слову, это файл шрифта имеет у вас название "Pravda_Fixed_Pitch.otf", вангую, что семейство надо указывать без подчёркиваний с пробелами, а может и слитно. Как-нибудь так: `font-family: "Pravda Fixed Pitch";